# How to query Hyperledger Fabric Go Chaincode by using the node.js SDK and TLS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I created my own Hyperledger Fabric which is up and running. I also installed the Fabcar Sample Chaincode given by the "Writing Your First Application Tutorial" on http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release/write_first_app.html. I also started the Fabcar Sample Network (as described in the First Application Tutorial) and I was able to start the node.js JavaScript Files which help to create an Admin, an User and to query the ledger or even invoke the chaincode.

Now I would like to do all these things with my own network. So I used the node.js files (admin.js, query.js, etc.) given by the tutorial as basis.

BUT:

The network I created uses TLS, the tutorial network does not. Although I was able to create the Admin and User account (just by using https instead of http), I have trouble to query (not even invoke) the chaincode on the ledger. I figured out, that I have to use grpcs instead of grpc and that I  have to provide the certificate pem file in order to be able to establish the connection. I tried so, but I got this error:

```
Store path:/home/artur/network-
projects/firstNetworkStepByStep/frontend/hfc-key-store
Successfully loaded user1 from persistence
E0220 00:03:25.937319415   31717 ssl_transport_security.c:584] Could not load any root certificate.
E0220 00:03:25.937350289   31717 ssl_transport_security.c:1297] Cannot load server root certificates.
E0220 00:03:25.937362437   31717 security_connector.c:857]   Handshaker factory creation failed with TSI_INVALID_ARGUMENT.
E0220 00:03:25.937368116   31717 secure_channel_create.c:112] Failed to create secure subchannel for secure name 'localhost:7051'
E0220 00:03:25.937372606   31717 secure_channel_create.c:143] Failed to create subchannel arguments during subchannel creation.
```

I tried to provide different kind of pem file TLS certificates which I generated at the beginning of building my network by using the cryptogen tool provided by Hyperledger Fabic, but none of these worked. I used only the pem files in the crypto-config folder for my peer1, since I installed and instantiated the chaincode only on this peer and would like to query only this peer for test purposes first.

So my questions are:

1. Which of the all these pem TLS certificates which were generated for the organization do I have to provide to the Hyperledger Fabric node.js SDK, when I used the Admin of my Org1, which successfully enrolled the user User1, in order to just query the ledger?
2. Is there a specific place where I have to put this certificate or do I specify the absolute path to the certificate in my JavaScript?

Here is my node.js JavaScript code snippet which is called:

```
 var Fabric_Client = require('fabric-client');
    var path = require('path');
    var util = require('util');
    var os = require('os');

    var fabric_client = new Fabric_Client();

    // setup the fabric network
    var channel = fabric_client.newChannel('mychannel');
    //without tls pem certificate:
    //var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpcs://localhost:7051');

    var tls_cert_path = path.join(__dirname, 'tls_cert', 'tlsca.org1.example.com-cert.pem');

    console.log('tls_cert_path:' + tls_cert_path);

    //var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpcs://localhost:7051');
    var peer = fabric_client.newPeer('grpcs://localhost:7051',{pem: tls_cert_path});

    channel.addPeer(peer);

    //
    var member_user = null;
    var store_path = path.join(__dirname, 'hfc-key-store');
    console.log('Store path:'+store_path);
    var tx_id = null;

    // create the key value store as defined in the fabric-client/config/default.json 'key-value-store' setting
    Fabric_Client.newDefaultKeyValueStore({ path: store_path
    }).then((state_store) => {
        // assign the store to the fabric client
        fabric_client.setStateStore(state_store);
        var crypto_suite = Fabric_Client.newCryptoSuite();
        // use the same location for the state store (where the users' certificate are kept)
        // and the crypto store (where the users' keys are kept)
        var crypto_store = Fabric_Client.newCryptoKeyStore({path: store_path});
        crypto_suite.setCryptoKeyStore(crypto_store);
        fabric_client.setCryptoSuite(crypto_suite);

        // get the enrolled user from persistence, this user will sign all requests
        return fabric_client.getUserContext('user1', true);
    }).then((user_from_store) => {
        if (user_from_store && user_from_store.isEnrolled()) {
            console.log('Successfully loaded user1 from persistence');
            member_user = user_from_store;
        } else {
            throw new Error('Failed to get user1.... run registerUser.js');
        }

        // queryCar chaincode function - requires 1 argument, ex: args: ['CAR4'],
        // queryAllCars chaincode function - requires no arguments , ex: args: [''],
        const request = {
            //targets : --- letting this default to the peers assigned to the channel
            chaincodeId: 'mycc',
            fcn: 'query',
            args: ['a']
        };

        // send the query proposal to the peer
        return channel.queryByChaincode(request);
    }).then((query_responses) => {
        console.log("Query has completed, checking results");
        // query_responses could have more than one  results if there multiple peers were used as targets
        if (query_responses && query_responses.length == 1) {
            if (query_responses[0] instanceof Error) {
                console.error("error from query = ", query_responses[0]);
            } else {
                console.log("Response is ", query_responses[0].toString());
            }
        } else {
            console.log("No payloads were returned from query");
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.error('Failed to query successfully :: ' + err);
    });
```

Any ideas or suggestions?

**EDIT 2018.02.21 09:22 CET: Added crypto-config.yaml and crypto.yaml source code:**

crypto-config.yaml:

```
OrdererOrgs:
  - Name: Orderer
    Domain: example.com
    Specs:
      - Hostname: orderer
      
PeerOrgs:
  - Name: Org1
    Domain: org1.example.com    
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1

  - Name: Org2
    Domain: org2.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1

  - Name: Org3
    Domain: org3.example.com
    Template:
      Count: 2
    Users:
      Count: 1
```

configtx.yaml:

```
Profiles:        
    TwoOrgsOrdererGenesis:
        Orderer:
            <<: *OrdererDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *OrdererOrg
        Consortiums:
            SampleConsortium:
                Organizations:
                    - *Org1
                    - *Org2
                    - *Org3
    TwoOrgsChannel:
        Consortium: SampleConsortium
        Application:
            <<: *ApplicationDefaults
            Organizations:
                - *Org1
                - *Org2
                - *Org3

Organizations:

    - &OrdererOrg
        Name: OrdererOrg
        ID: OrdererMSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/msp

    - &Org1
        Name: Org1MSP
        ID: Org1MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org1.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org2
        Name: Org2MSP
        ID: Org2MSP
        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org2.example.com
              Port: 7051

    - &Org3
        Name: Org3MSP
        ID: Org3MSP

        MSPDir: crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/msp

        AnchorPeers:
            - Host: peer0.org3.example.com
              Port: 7051

Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  
    OrdererType: solo

    Addresses:
        - orderer.example.com:7050

    BatchTimeout: 2s
    BatchSize:
        MaxMessageCount: 10
        AbsoluteMaxBytes: 99 MB
       PreferredMaxBytes: 512 KB

    Kafka:
        Brokers:
            - 127.0.0.1:9092

    Organizations:

Application: &ApplicationDefaults

    Organizations:
```

**EDIT 2018.02.21 13:14 CET: Added docker compose file:**

```
# Copyright IBM Corp. All Rights Reserved.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

version: '2'

networks:
  byfn:

services:

  ca0:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org1.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_KEY_ORG1}
    ports:
      - "7054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org1.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_KEY_ORG1} -b adminorg1:adminpworg1 -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org1.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  ca1:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org2.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_KEY_ORG2}
    ports:
      - "8054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org2.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_KEY_ORG2} -b adminorg2:adminpworg2 -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org2.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn 
      
  ca2:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.org3.example.com
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_CERTFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_TLS_KEYFILE=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_KEY_ORG3}
    ports:
      - "9054:7054"
    command: sh -c 'fabric-ca-server start --ca.certfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/ca.org3.example.com-cert.pem --ca.keyfile /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config/${CA_KEY_ORG3} -b adminorg3:adminpworg3 -d'
    volumes:
      - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/ca/:/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server-config
    container_name: ca.org3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn

  orderer.example.com:
    networks:
      - byfn
    container_name: orderer.example.com
    image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISMETHOD=file
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_GENESISFILE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPID=OrdererMSP
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOCALMSPDIR=/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
      # enabled TLS
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_PRIVATEKEY=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.key
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_CERTIFICATE=/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/server.crt
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_TLS_ROOTCAS=[/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls/ca.crt]
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric
    command: orderer
    #command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
    - ./channel-artifacts/genesis.block:/var/hyperledger/orderer/orderer.genesis.block
    - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp:/var/hyperledger/orderer/msp
    - ./crypto-config/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/tls/:/var/hyperledger/orderer/tls
    ports:
      - 7050:7050

  peer0.org1.example.com:
    networks:
      - byfn
    container_name: peer0.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb0:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb0
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 7051:7051
      - 7053:7053

  couchdb0:
    container_name: couchdb0
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "5984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org1.example.com:
    networks:
      - byfn
    container_name: peer1.org1.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org1.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb1:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb1
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer1.org1.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls

    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053

  couchdb1:
    container_name: couchdb1
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "6984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb2:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb2
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 9051:7051
      - 9053:7053
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb2:
    container_name: couchdb2
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "7984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org2.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org2.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org2.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org2.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org2MSP

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb3:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb3
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer1.org2.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 10051:7051
      - 10053:7053
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb3:
    container_name: couchdb3
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "8984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer0.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer0.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0.org3.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org3.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer0.org3.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer0.org3.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb4:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb4
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer0.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 11051:7051
      - 11053:7053
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb4:
    container_name: couchdb4
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "9984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  peer1.org3.example.com:
    container_name: peer1.org3.example.com
    extends:
      file: peer-base.yaml
      service: peer-base
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1.org3.example.com
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer1.org3.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_EXTERNALENDPOINT=peer1.org3.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_BOOTSTRAP=peer1.org3.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org3MSP

      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_STATEDATABASE=CouchDB
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_COUCHDBADDRESS=couchdb5:5984
      # The CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME and CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD
      # provide the credentials for ledger to connect to CouchDB.  The username and password must
      # match the username and password set for the associated CouchDB.
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_USERNAME=
      - CORE_LEDGER_STATE_COUCHDBCONFIG_PASSWORD=
    depends_on:
      - couchdb5
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer1.org3.example.com/msp:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp
        - ./crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org3.example.com/peers/peer1.org3.example.com/tls:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/tls
    ports:
      - 12051:7051
      - 12053:7053
    networks:
      - byfn

  couchdb5:
    container_name: couchdb5
    image: hyperledger/fabric-couchdb
    # Populate the COUCHDB_USER and COUCHDB_PASSWORD to set an admin user and password
    # for CouchDB.  This will prevent CouchDB from operating in an "Admin Party" mode.
    environment:
      - COUCHDB_USER=
      - COUCHDB_PASSWORD=
    # Comment/Uncomment the port mapping if you want to hide/expose the CouchDB service,
    # for example map it to utilize Fauxton User Interface in dev environments.
    ports:
      - "10984:5984"
    networks:
      - byfn

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: hyperledger/fabric-tools
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0.org1.example.com:7051
      - CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.crt
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/server.key
      - CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt
      - CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    #command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/arphi.sh; sleep infinity'
    #command: /bin/bash -c './scripts/script.sh ${CHANNEL_NAME} ${DELAY}; sleep $TIMEOUT'
    #command: tail -f /dev/null
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./../chaincode/:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/chaincode/go
        - ./crypto-config:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/
        - ./scripts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/scripts/
        - ./channel-artifacts:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel-artifacts
    depends_on:
      - orderer.example.com
      - peer0.org1.example.com
      - peer1.org1.example.com
      - peer0.org2.example.com
      - peer1.org2.example.com
      - peer0.org3.example.com
      - peer1.org3.example.com
    networks:
      - byfn
```

Comment: can you post your yaml files?

Comment: Sure, please find the source code of my config files in the text.

Comment: also compose file.

Comment: Added docker compose file.

Comment: I am also stuck with the same issue, can anybody help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Check that prerequisites are satisfied as mentioned on the [SDK Github](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node#build-and-test). I encountered similar SSL and TLS errors after accidentally changing my Node.js version to 10.15 which is unsupported.